# Postgresql gem custom type cast Numeric to Decimal/Float

Tags: ruby, postgresql, automation, casting, rubygems

Actual:
Decimal/Float values are getting type casted to Integer.

Expected:
Decimal/Float values are getting type casted to Integer. It should return exact type of the value rather than converting it.

Tried:
qry     = "
SELECT CAST (column_name AS FLOAT) FROM TABLE table_name
"
@postgres.single_result(qry)

E.g. column has value as 14.7 which is float but PG is converting it to integer.

Reference:
https://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/BinaryEncoder/Float4.html
https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg

Comment: 1) What is the actual type of column `column_name`? 2) This is not on Postgres end: `select cast(14.7 as float);  14.7` or `select cast('14.7' as float); 14.7`.

Comment: Can you post the custom type definition?